# anyone know why my forms are appearing as a class and not a field? [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone know why this is happening?

the Main form is recognised as a class instead of a field?? this is on my SeasonProgress.vb form however seasonProgress is recognised as a field and not a class on `c2s7Menu.vb`

as a result i cannot use `c2s7Menu.show()` in the `seasonprogress.vb` form

[image: Picture]

EDIT: now getting this error?
[image: picture]

Comment: Probably because Forms **are** classes. Are you used to default instances of Forms? You should most probably forget these ever existed.

Comment: could u please explain how i could get the form to show then?

Comment: Creating a new Instance of it, as everywhere else:  `dim menu as new c2s7Menu() menu.Show()`, or `menu.Show(Me)`, or `menu.ShowDialog()` or `menu.ShowDialog(Me)`.

Comment: thanks mate! appreciate the help its working now<3

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: Don't post images of code, it's not acceptable here. You need to copy and paste your code as text -- Remove that Field declaration, you need to declare the new instance of that Form in the same block of code that shows it. Make sure that your `c2s7Menu` Form is **NOT** creating an instance of the Form that shows it, otherwise you have one Form that instantiate the other until you get a stackoverflow exception.